# Bash reading value from a file to set a variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to clean up some of my code to remove a lot of my repeated code for running tests and monitoring logs through soft and hard reboots.

The script I have will cycle through 7 sets of tests and output the results to their each respective folders in the /persist/ directory. I have a file which contains nothing but an integer of 1-7 to record which stage of testing I am on (has to persist through reboots) in

```
/persist/whichtest
```

The below tests/folders are located in `/persist/` for my results to go into

```
Boot
stress
swap
longevity
gps
platform
gpslong
```

How would i go about setting "${testname[i]}" to equal one of my test names depending on the number set in `/persist/whichtest`?

So each time it performs the tests in `Boot`, it will output the results to `/persist/Boot` and when the tests of `gps` are being performed, the results will go to `/persist/gps`

```
function logs {
  echo "insertlog stuff here" >> /persist/"${testname[i]}"/test1.log
  echo "insertlog stuff here" >> /persist/"${testname[i]}"/test2.log
  echo "insertlog stuff here" >> /persist/"${testname[i]}"/test3.log
}
```

```
declare -a testname=(Boot stress swap longevity gps platform gpslong)
```

When it is running the first round of tests, the results will go into `/persist/Boot/`

When it is running second round of tests, the results will go into `/persist/stress/`

Then to follow the same pattern for each test case

This is the function I was looking to use

```
function errorlog {
        echo "" "$(date)" | tee -a /persist/"${testname[i]}"/error.log
        /bin/dmesg | grep -i "seg\|error\|fault\|unified\|qmi" >> /persist/"${testname[i]}"/error.log
        grep -i "seg\|error\|fault\|unified\|qmi" >> /persist/"${testname[i]}"/error.log
}
```

I've hit a bit of a wall so any advice is appreciated.

Edited my original question, sorry it wasn't very well worded. Hopefully this will make things more clear.

[Full script is here](https://pastebin.com/GLUTDrRk)

Comment: A lot of clarification needed here.  What does it mean that a test is completed?  What happens when "number" exceeds 8?  What are you trying to accomplish in function logs?    Please provide sample data and expected results.  And clear up any ambiguity as mentioned.

Comment: Sorry @Dennis you are correct. I have updated my question with more information to clear up the ambiguity, my apologies for the poor wording. Hopefully this is more clear?

Comment: Why do you care which number you are currently on? Just keeping track of the name of the test would simplify your logic significantly. Just loop over the tokens and skip any which already exist. If you want to rerun a test, delete or rename its output directory.

Comment: `echo "" "$(date)"` is a classic [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) - just `date +' %c'` to get a space before the date stamp.

Comment: @tripleee because the value in /persist/whichtest is the way i'm keeping track of the tests which have been performed because of the reboots that happen on each phase of testing. Otherwise i have no way to keep track of all of the tests. I'll update my post with a pastebin of my full code to not spam everything up. Thank you for the echo advice :)

Comment: That doesn't explain why you want to use numbers for this. If the existence of the output directory is not sufficient, can you add a flag file like `/persist/Boot/DONE` to signal when the test is complete?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an associative array (Like a dictionary in many other languages):

```
testname=( ["1"]="A" ["2"]="B" ["3"]="C" )
echo "${testname[1]}"
```

This will output `A`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter in the loop.

```
testname=(a b c d e f g)
n=1
for f in "${testname[@]}"; do
  printf '%d %s\n' "$((n++))" "$f"
done
```

The output

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
```

If that is fine, then use an associative array. Just declare it inside the loop.

```
testname=(a b c d e f g)

n=1
for f in "${testname[@]}"; do
  declare -A output[$((n++))]="$f"
done
```

The output

```
printf '%s\n' "${output[@]}"

a
b
c
d
e
f
g

printf '%s\n' "${!output[@]}"

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Have a look at the [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) section of the bash manual.
Also [Using arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Other answerers seem to have missed that the question is about *reading value from a file to set a variable*. The `testname` array you have already declared, although with a missing `h` if *the number goes from 1-8*. The convenient Bash syntax for inserting a file's content into a command is `$(<...)`, so you can set `i` to the required index with `i=$(</persist/whichtest)-1`. The subtraction of 1 is necessary because array indexes start from 0. (Of course this subtraction is only evaluated within the `${testname[i]}` indexing brackets.)